# How many combinations does Android pattern have?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, additive-combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

[image: Example]

Rules-
1) At-least 4 and at-max 9 dots must be connected.
2) There can be no jumps[image]

3) Once a dot is crossed, you can jump over it.

Comment: See OEIS: [A163889](http://oeis.org/A163889). The total number of unlock patterns is A163889(4) + ... + A163889(9) = 389130. [Edit: the OEIS might have A163889(4) wrong -- can anyone verify if that term is 1624 or 1642?]

Comment: Start by enumerating legal first arrows.  If I understand the rules, there are at most 40 such. Then do legal second arrows  (If you use symmetry, there are 7 branches to explore).  You now have a handle on a good upper bound, as there will be a little more than 6! ways to finish each branch. This question is better asked at a different forum.

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment (which I can't edit anymore) -- the 4th term of the OEIS entry was indeed incorrect (it was 1642 rather than the correct 1624). I have since corrected it. The final answer to this problem is 389112 (not 389130).

Comment: Regardless of the number of combinations, this isn't a very secure way to lock a phone unless you thoroughly clean the screen after touching it.